# what is the right way (if any) to use the slim container on a non controller class

Tags: slim

I have an isolated class file that is outside of a slim controller or cycle:

```
class UserModel
{


    public function getSingleUser( string $field, $value )
    {
        return ( new DbSql )->db()->table( 'users' )->where( $field, $value )->first();
    }
}
```

I want to replace the instantiation of the DbSql class by access to this service that is also registered in the slim container.

Question:

1) How do I access the slim container from this class?

2) I didn't see such example in the doc, is it something that should be avoided? Should I avoid accessing slim container from outside slim controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't see such example in the doc

Thats probably because the container is a dependency from Slim -> [Pimple](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple)

> Should I avoid accessing slim container from outside slim controller ?

No, actually the container should be used for constructing all objects

> How do I access the slim container from this class

You shouldn't access the DI-Container in the class. Rather the container should inject the needed instances in the constructor.

So first, when you havn't already done this add `DbSql` to the container:

```
$app = \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['DbSql'] = function($c) {
    return new DbSql();
};
```

Then add the `UserModel` to the container and add `DbSql` as constructor parameter

```
$container['UserModel'] = function($c) {
    return new UserModel($c['DbSql']);
};
```

Add a constructor to the `UserModel`

```
class UserModel {
    private $dbSql;

    public function __construct(DbSql $dbSql) {
        $this->dbSql = $dbSql;
    }

    public function getSingleUser( string $field, $value ) {
        return $this->dbSql->db()->table( 'users' )->where( $field, $value )->first();
    }
}
```

Now you can get the `UserModel` from the container

```
$userModel = $container['UserModel'];

$user = $userModel->getSingleUser('name', 'jmattheis');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it necessary to add DbSql to the constructor in UserModel ? Once DbSql is in the container, can't it just be pulled out directly from the container ?

Comment: @RobertBrax you could make the container globally available, but this would be not that beautiful. It should be like in my answer (also like in the Pimple documentation).